# Fetching PDO - Custom blog

Tags: php, pdo

I'm building a blog for a website and I'm learning PDO as I go. I need some help with some URL and PDO stuff.

Currently I can display my blog entries and all associated info on the `blog` page. When I click on the title (linked to the full blog post) I am doing this:

```
<h2><a href="blog.php?<?php echo urlencode($row['title'])?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></a></h2>
```

The output gives me something like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/blog.php?my+blog+post+title+
```

So, I figured I'd use `$_GET` to see if `$row['title']` is set. If so, display the full blog post else display all blog entries like so:

```
<?php
if ($_GET == urlencode($sth->fetch())) { ?> **//This is where I'm stuck**
... Code here to display full blog post

<?php } else { ?>

<?php
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {  ?>
.... Code here to display ALL blog posts
```

So, how do I use `$_GET` to check if the title matches and if so, display the full post? If this isn't the most efficient way, please recommend an alternative. Thanks!!

Comment: Why not use `$_GET['id']` instead of title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to do it like Stack Overflow; look:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610314/fetching-pdo-custom-blog
```

They have both the post ID and the title, but they only use the ID to fetch the right data.

Comment: That would make sense :). thanks. So, I'm checking `$_GET` before I define `$row`. How can I use PDO to return JUST the `id` so I'm able to do a comparison?